# how to use react-navigation hide one page header ,not the method "headerMode:none",i try this way but error

Tags: android, reactjs

[image]

[image]

how to use react-navigation hide one page header ,not the method "headerMode:none",i try this way but error

Comment: Your question is very unclear, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide somerelevant source code